# Pydantic V2 `model_validator(mode="wrap")` - How to use `ModelWrapValidatorHandler`

Tags: python, pydantic

In short I want to implement a `model_validator(mode="wrap")` which takes a `ModelWrapValidatorHandler` as argument. I guess this validation handler just calls at least all before-validators.

```py
class A(BaseModel):
    x: str
    y: int

    model_config = ConfigDict(frozen=True)

    @model_validator(mode="wrap")
    def something(cls, values: Any, handler: ModelWrapValidatorHandler["A"]):
        # values seems to be a dict most of the cases
        result = handler(values)
        # result always seems to be an instance of A
        result2 = handler(values, outer_location="x")
        # Seems to do the same thing
        # result3 = handler(values["x"], outer_location="x")
        # Doesn't work because the value of x would get passed to model-before-validators
        # which is obviously expected to be e.g. a dictionary of all fields.

        return result
```

I can't get to it. I couldn't find any documentation of it. There is no example usage or similar documented on this ModelWrapValidator as well. With my debugger I can't even get into the implemented handler function. I guess it lives somewhere in the new Rust-core [pydantic-core](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-core).

So essentially I have two questions: What does `outer_location` do? Or how do I get to the implementation - is there anyway to dig into it with the debugger?

Why do I need this:
I can't use before-validators due to execution ordering. After-validators doesn't suite my needs as well because my model is configured to be frozen and I need to mutate the values. That's why I cannot simply throw the handler on it since it returns instances of my class. Yes, I'm aware that I can use `object.__setattr__(result, field_name, new_field_value)` to circumvent the "frozen" state of the instance but that would be my last resort.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you import `ModelWrapValidatorHandler` which is to my knowledge only the `protocol` used for wrap-validaton in `pydantic>=2.0` and not `type(handler)`. But indeed when you specify `mode="wrap"` in either `field_validator` or `model_validator`, the function expects a `handler` argument which runs the before-validators along with the standard pydantic validation. The following code should work:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class A(BaseModel):
    x: str
    y: int

    @model_validator(mode="wrap")
    def something(self, handler) -> 'A':
        # Before: self is raw input
        print(type(self))  # dict

        # After: self is pydantic model 'A'
        validated_self = handler(self)
        print(type(validated_self))  # 'A'

        # now include some after validation
        validated_self.x = 'hard-coded'

        return validated_self

a = A(x='s', y=2716)
print(a)
```

The misconception in your code was that your syntax applies to `field_validator` as it expects as first variable a `values` argument which represents the value of the field to be validated. For `model_validator` this role is taken up by `self`. Moreover, `before` validators are `classmethods` but `wrap` validators are not.

Comment: Your code does the same es mine. The `model_validator` decorator does not differentiate between the modes when it comes to fill in the parameters to the validator function (as far as I've seen). I.e. classmethod signatures work exactly the same as instance method signatures. You can try it out if you don't believe me :) The real problem is that my model is `frozen` so I cannot overwrite anything after applying the handler. (last paragraph of my post)

Comment: What I want: Iterating through all fields, applying before validators and potentially overwrite the fields values (keep in mind that it is `frozen` after a simple call to `handler`). I was hoping that the option `outer_location` which is stated in the official `Protocol` class for this has some hidden functionality which could help me.

Comment: Btw, the actual type of `handler` is `<class 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidatorCallable'>` but this doesn't exist in the module `pydantic_core._pydantic_core` so it is loaded dynamically somewhere.

Comment: Same problem here with `frozen` attributes. Did you find a workaround?